# Why doesn't Django's per-site cache middleware work for me?

Tags: python, django, memcached, django-middleware, django-cache

I am using Django 1.3 beta 1 and set up memcached. I made changes to my `settings.py` per [Django's instructions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache):

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    #'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 100000
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = 'site_cache'
```

This is the test view function I'm hitting:

```
def home(request):

    print 'uncached'

    # ...View's code...
```

I always get `uncached` printed on the development server's output and I always get hits to the database. Why? Am I missing something or just misunderstanding caching completely?

### Edit #1:

[Template fragment caching](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) works perfectly fine. Am I just missing something? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the memcache instance and checking to see if anything is cached? It appears like you're doing the right thing, provided you're using django 1.3

Comment: Yes. I see set's and get's. Anything specifically that I should look at?

Comment: Beaming, did you find a reason why it did not work for you? Having similar problem with website recently upgraded from django 1.2.

Comment: Same issue here.  Did anyone figure this out?

Comment: I never did figure this one out. I have unmarked it as answered. Albeit, I am no longer working on this issue so I wouldn't know how to confirm whether an answer addresses it.

Comment: In my case, this was due to a [combination of sessions and google analytics](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/The-state-of-per-site-per-view-middleware-caching-in-Django-td486447.html).  With the google tracker commented out the cache is working.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have everything set up correctly. The only possible caveat I can see in the documentation is the following:

```
The cache middleware caches every page that doesn't have GET or POST parameters.
```

Unfortunately, I'm assuming you already know this and it won't help you.

Comment: Yes. I know that and have confirmed that the `request.GET` and `request.POST` are empty. This one has me stumped but I've put it on the backburner for the time being and will investigate it sometime next week.